# How to make query from related models in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I happen to have: Sale model that has: `id, product_id, qty, s_price`; Product model that has: `id, category_id, name`; Category model that has: `id, name`

Currently l can make this query successfully:

```
 $sales = Sale::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
                ->whereBetween('created_at', [$startDate, $endDate])
                ->whereBetween('qty', [$lQty, $uQty])
                ->paginate(11);
```

I know the category_id and want to filter out only sales of products that belong a particular category. Something like:

```
 $sales = Sale::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
                    ->whereBetween('created_at', [$startDate, $endDate])
                    ->whereBetween('qty', [$lQty, $uQty])
                    ->where('category_id', '=', 5)
                    ->paginate(11);
```

Comment: So... What's the question? Are you getting some kind of an error? What results are you getting/what results are you expecting?

Comment: I get this error  Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'category_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `sales` where `created_at` between 2016-08-15 and 2016-08-16 and `qty` between 0 and 100000 and `category_id` = 5)

Comment: I definitely have defined relationship between products and sales

Comment: what is the relation between sale and product there is no such sale_id in product model?It will throw error

Comment: `public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
    }` @pari

Comment: So your `sales` table doesn't have a `category_id` column. Nothing confusing about that. You'll have to construct a query from your existing tables by `left join`ing any tables required until you can query against a `category_id` column.

Comment: I thought Laravel provided for description of relationships on models to enable making of complex queries without the need for joins @Lewis

Comment: Are you sure 1 product belongs to only 1 sale? Relation between sale and product should be many-to-many relation.

Comment: They do provide relations, but you need to access them the correct way. See [querying relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations) documentation. Right now you're not accessing the relationship.

Comment: If you're trying to query against a specific column, you'll still need to do joins. If you want to return a subset of records from a relationship based on their ID, it would be done using something like `->with(["relationship", => function($query){ $query->where("id", "=", 5); }]);`

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
$sales = Sale::whereHas('product', function ($query) {
                $query->where('category_id', '=', 5);
            })
            ->whereBetween('created_at', [$startDate, $endDate])
            ->whereBetween('qty', [$lQty, $uQty])
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
            ->paginate(11);
```